# как расположить элементы

Tags: html, css

как расположить элементы как на макете?
То что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

макет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 248px;
  font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #F34A4A;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently */
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 87px;
  background: #222F34;
}


/*.main {
      background: #615049;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }*/

.vl {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-left: 6px solid #F1D3BC;
  height: 76px;
  width: 2px;
}

.link {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #F34A4A;
  height: auto;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #d83232;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #615049;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Отменяем подчеркивание у ссылки */
}

.foot {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #F1D3BC;
  border-radius: 53px;
  margin: 60px;
}

.text {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
  padding: 1.5%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 43px;
  color: #222F34;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.name {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 43px;
  color: #F34A4A;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.logoMin {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.textNews {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #222F34;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <h1 class="logo">BaseSec</h1>
  <div class="vl"></div>
  <a class="link" href="news.html">НОВОСТИ</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">СТАТЬИ</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">ПРОФИЛЬ</a>
</div>
<div class="foot">
  <div class="">
    <img class="logoMin" src="unknown1.svg">
    <h2 class="name">Сайт кибер безопастности BaseSec</h2>
    <p class="textNews">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.foot-child {
 display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "red green" "red blue ";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  background: orange;
}

.name {
  grid-area: green;
  background: green;
}

.logoMin {
  grid-area: red;
  background: red;
}

.textNews {
  grid-area: blue;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="foot-child">
  <img class="logoMin" src="unknown1.svg">
  <h2 class="name">Сайт кибер безопастности BaseSec</h2>
  <p class="textNews">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```